# jupyter lab (not pip installed but GitHub code) not loading icons when opened via docker

Tags: css, docker, jupyter

I am trying to load JupyterLab (by building the GitHub source code and not installing it using 'pip'), by opening it via a docker container, but it is not loading the icons which are accessed by css variables (e.g. :- `background_image = var(--jp-terminal)`). To be precise only the python icons for 'Notebook' and 'Console' are loading because they are loaded by html  tags. The rest are loaded by variables as mentioned before.

My current directory looks like this :-

```
bin      docker       jupyterlab
```

The 'bin' folder contains the 'run.sh' file, the 'docker' folder contains the 'Dockerfile' and the 'jupyter lab' folder contains the source code and files for jupyter lab taken from GitHub.

Here is my Dockerfile :-

```
FROM centos:latest

RUN yum -y install epel-release \
    yum -y install python-devel.x86_64 python27-python-devel.x86_64 gcc \
    yum -y install nodejs \
    yum -y install python-pip \
    yum -y install sudo

RUN pip install --upgrade setuptools pip 

RUN yum -y update

COPY jupyterlab /jupyterlab

RUN cd /jupyterlab && pip install -e . && jlpm install && jlpm run build && jlpm run build:core && jupyter lab build

COPY bin/run.sh /run.sh RUN chmod +x /run.sh

EXPOSE 8888

ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/sh", "/run.sh"]


Here is the 'run.sh' file which is used as entrypoint :-

jupyter notebook --generate-config

mkdir -p -m 700 /home/jupyter/.jupyter/ && echo "c.NotebookApp.token = ''" >> /home/jupyter/.jupyter/jupyter_notebook_config.py

jupyter lab --ip=* --no-browser --allow-root
```

Any suggestions?